# Residue fields of gaussian primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I just started with algebraic number theory and need some help: In the ring of Gaussian integers a prime $p$ with $p=1\bmod 4$ splits into a product of two irreducible elements $(a+bi)(a-bi)$, with $a^2+b^2=p$, if $p=3\bmod 4$ then $p$ stays prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and if $p=2$ then $p$ ramifies as $(1+i)^2$. I wonder how I can see that the different residue fields that you get from the prime ideals generated by the irreducible elements just described have $p$, $p^2$ and $2$ elements respectively. I.e. the norm of the generator gives the size of the field. Why?

Comment: If $p = 1 \bmod 4$ and $a^2 + b^2 = p$, then $a+bi$ is a factor of $p$, so the ring homomorphism ${\mathbf Z} \rightarrow {\mathbf Z}[i]/(a+bi)$ kills $p$ and thus induces a ring homomorphism $f \colon {\mathbf Z}/(p) \rightarrow {\mathbf Z}[i]/(a+bi)$.  It's injective since *any* ring homomorphism out of a field is injective. The meaty part is showing this is surjective, and for that it's enough to see that $i \equiv c \bmod a+bi$ for an integer $c$. Well, $i \bmod a+bi$ is a square root of $-1$, and $-1$ is a square in ${\mathbf Z}/(p)$ because $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. Therefore the image [...]

Comment: of $f$ includes two square roots of $-1$ inside ${\mathbf Z}[i]/(a+bi)$. Those are the only ones possible because ${\mathbf Z}[i]/(a+bi)$ is a field (the number $a+bi$ is prime in the PID ${\mathbf Z}[i]$, so working mod $a+bi$ is a field). Therefore $i \bmod a+bi$ has to be in the image of $f$, so $f$ is surjective and thus an isomorphism. (Wait, an easier soln: it's easy to solve for $i$ in $a+bi \equiv 0 \bmod a+bi$ because $b$ has an inverse mod $p$.) Thus ${\mathbf Z}[i]/(a+bi)$ has order $p$. The other cases of primes in ${\mathbf Z}[i]$ are simpler.

Comment: Another way: think about the tower of ideals $(p) \subset (a+bi) \subset {\mathbf Z}[i]$. I hope you can see that $(p)$ has index $p^2$ in ${\mathbf Z}[i]$ (think about what a congruence mod $p{\mathbf Z}[i]$ really means on the real and imaginary parts). Therefore $(a+bi)$ has index 1, $p$, or $p^2$ in ${\mathbf Z}[i]$. Since $a$ and $b$ are not 0, $(a+bi) \not= (p)$. Since $a+bi$ is not a unit (it has norm $p$), $(a+bi) \not= {\mathbf Z}[i]$. So the only choice is for $(a+bi)$ to have index $p$ in ${\mathbf Z}[i]$.

Comment: @Kcd why is this a comment, and not an answer?

Comment: @KCd , you should *really* gather together your comments into one answer...a pity this question will go unanswered when you've done all that writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the wonderful answer of KCD, we can also avail of [the theorem of *Dedekind*](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1930-032-04/S0002-9947-1930-1501568-4/S0002-9947-1930-1501568-4.pdf). Also see [IV.XXXI](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Ant/AntChapter4.pdf).

Now we take $f(x)=x^2+1$.
If $p\equiv 1\pmod4$, then there is an integer $a$ such that $a^2\equiv -1\pmod p$. So, according to the theorem, $(p)=(p,i-a)(p,i+a)$. Now $\mathbb Z[i]/(p,i-a)\cong (\mathbb Z[i]/(i-a))/(p)\cong \mathbb Z/(p)$, so the residue field in question has $p$ elements.
If $p\equiv -1\pmod 4$, then $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $Z/(p)$, so $(p)\mathbb Z[i]=(p,i^2+1)=(p)$, and hence the residue field $\mathbb Z[i]/(p)\cong \mathbb Z[x]/(p,x^2+1)\cong (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[x]/(x^2+1)$ is an extension of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ of degree $2$, namely, it has $p^2$ elements.
If $p=2$, then $x^2+1\equiv (x-1)^2\pmod p$, so $(2)=(2,i-1)^2$, and the residue field $\mathbb Z[i]/(2,i-1)\cong \mathbb Z/(2)$ has $2$ elements.

Inform me, if the notations are too ambiguous, or if some errors take place here.
Thanks for any attention.